# Too many redirects - regarding .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked at many other questions, but they don't seem to help me. This is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app_sys.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I use CodeIgniter. PHP 5.4. Apache 2.4.6. Please correct me!

Answer (score 1):

In your .htaccess rule

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

make this infinite redirects

I think you want make redirect from **www.domain.tld** to **domain.tld** forgot `RewriteCond` for this rule

If you need this, then just add next line before this rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.domain.com [nocase]
```

Comment: I see.. can you provide an example or fix the aforementioned code? Am clueless at the moment. How should I add the RewriteCond?

Comment: Doesn't work. I wanted the .htaccess file to make a website.com/login redirect to website.com/?login, well if you get me. That's how CodeIgniter works.